# Поиск необходмых заголовков

Tags: java, алгоритм, jsoup

Есть метод, который считает хедеры для таблицы

```
private List<String> headers(String html)
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Elements header;
    Element firstThead = doc.select("thead").first();
    Elements trOfFirstThead = firstThead.children();
    for (Element tr : firstThead.children())
    {
        Elements select = tr.select("th");
        for (Element th : select)
        {
            String s = th.attributes().get("rowspan");
            if (!s.isEmpty() && s.equals(String.valueOf(trOfFirstThead.size())))
            {
                result.add(th.text());
            }
        }
    }
    header = trOfFirstThead.last().children();

    for (Element element : header)
    {
        if (element.tag().getName().equals(tag_th))
        {
            result.add(element.text());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Суть метода такова - на вход поступает таблица, у которой есть раздел `thead` и из него необходимо получить хедеры в виде коллекции строк. Если хедеры расположены в несколько рядов, то выбирается нижний ряд, и по нему берутся названия.

Данный алгоритм работает для таблиц, представленых под номерами **1**, **2**, и **3** ( см. вложение). Но для таблицы типа 4 хедеры находятся не правильно.

Требуемая коллекция :

**h4 h10 h11 h12 h6 h7**.

При работе алгоритма получается следующая коллекция :

**h4 h7 h10 h11 h12**.

Прошу помочь советом/алгоритмом, как можно реализовать нужное поведение.

**P.S.** исходный код таблиц.

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div>
        <p>Таблица 1</p>
        <table border="1">
         <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>h1</th>
          <th>h2</th>
          <th>h3</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
      </li>
          
      <li>
       <div>
        <p>Таблица 2</p>
        <table border="1">
         <thead>
         <tr>
          <th colspan="2">h4</th>
          <th>h5</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>h1</th>
          <th>h2</th>
          <th>h3</th>
         </tr>

         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
       <div>
        <p>Таблица 3</p>
        <table border="1">
         <thead>
         <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">h4</th>
          <th colspan="2">h5</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>h1</th>
          <th>h2</th>
         </tr>

         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       
       </div>
      </li>
      <li>
       <div>
        <p>Таблица 4</p>
        <table border="1">
         <thead>
         <tr>
          <th rowspan="3">h4</th>
          <th colspan="4">h5</th>
          <th rowspan="3">h7</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>h1</th>
          <th>h2</th>
          <th>h8</th>
          <th rowspan="2">h6</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th>h10</th>
          <th>h11</th>
          <th>h12</th>
         </tr>

         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>

         </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, решением будет реализация в каком-то объеме прописанного в HTML5 [алгоритма построения таблицы](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#forming-a-table), благо обработка `<thead>` там простая. Вот этот код выдает нужный результат на ваших примерах:

```
static class TableHeader {
    private String[][] cells;
    private int y_height = 0;
    private int x_width = 0;

    public TableHeader( int rows, int columns, Element thead ) {
        cells = new String[rows][columns];

        parseTHead( thead );
    }

    private void ensureCapacity( int rows, int columns ) {
        if ( rows <= cells.length && columns <= cells[0].length ) return;

        int nRows = Math.max( cells.length, rows );
        int nColumns = Math.max( cells[0].length, columns );

        String[][] newCells = new String[nRows][nColumns];
        for ( int row = 0; row < cells.length; row++ ) {
            System.arraycopy(cells[row], 0, newCells[row], 0, cells[row].length );
        }

        cells = newCells;
    }

    private void fill( String cellValue, int row, int col, int rowspan, int colspan ) {
        ensureCapacity( row + rowspan, col + colspan );
        for ( int r = 0; r < rowspan; r++ ) {
            for ( int c = 0; c < colspan; c++ ) {
                cells[row + r][col + c] = cellValue;
            }
        }
    }


    private int cellSpan( Element th, String attrName ) {
        String attrValue = th.attr( attrName );
        int result = 1;
        if ( attrValue.isEmpty() ) return result;
        try {
            result = Integer.parseInt( attrValue );
        } catch ( NumberFormatException ex ) { /*ignore*/ };
        return result;
    }

    // http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#algorithm-for-processing-row-groups
    private void parseTHead( Element thead ) {
        //int y_start = y_height; // #1
        int y_current = 0;
        final Elements rows = thead.children().select( "tr" );
        final int rowsNumber = rows.size();
        ensureCapacity(rowsNumber, x_width);
        for ( Element tr : rows ) { // #2
            //http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#algorithm-for-processing-rows
            if ( y_height == y_current ) {
                y_height += 1;
            }
            int x_current = 0;
            //TODO: Run the algorithm for growing 'downward-growing cells'.
            for ( Element currentCell : tr.children().select( "td, th" ) ) {
                //6. While xcurrent is less than xwidth and the slot with coordinate (xcurrent, ycurrent)
                //  already has a cell assigned to it, increase xcurrent by 1.
                while ( x_current < x_width && cells[y_current][x_current] != null ) x_current += 1;
                if ( x_current == x_width ) {
                    x_width += 1; //# 7
                }
                int colspan = cellSpan( currentCell, "colspan" ); //#8 
                int rowspan = cellSpan( currentCell, "rowspan" ); //#9
                if (colspan == 0) colspan = 1; 
                //TODO: 10. If rowspan is zero and the table element's Document is not set to quirks mode,
                // then let 'cell grows downward' be true, and set rowspan to 1.
                // Otherwise, let cell grows downward be false.
                //FIXME: не позволяем rowspan создавать больше строк, чем есть <tr>
                //  как этот вопрос решен в стандарте?
                rowspan = Math.min( rowsNumber - y_current, rowspan );
                if ( x_width < x_current + colspan ) x_width = x_current + colspan;
                if ( y_height < y_current + rowspan ) y_height = y_current + rowspan;
                // TODO: If any of the slots involved already had a cell covering them,
                //   then this is a table model error.
                //   Those slots now have two cells overlapping.
                fill( currentCell.text(), y_current, x_current, rowspan, colspan ); // #13
                // TODO: If 'cell grows downward' is true, then add the tuple
                //   {c, xcurrent, colspan} to the list of 'downward-growing cells'.
                x_current += colspan; //#15
            }
            y_current += 1;
        }
    }

    public List<String> lastRow() {
        return Arrays.stream( cells[y_height - 1]).limit( x_width ).collect( Collectors.toList());
    }
}

private static List<String> headers3(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Element firstThead = doc.select("thead").first();

    TableHeader header = new TableHeader(10, 10, firstThead);

    return header.lastRow();
}
```

В реализации не обрабатывается случай с `rowspan="0"`, вроде как все манипуляции с шириной и высотой можно закинуть в `fill`, и ни на чем, кроме ваших примеров я ее не проверял. В качестве бонуса, такой подход позволяет легко получить полный заголовок столбца.

upd: есть очевидная проблема со случаем, когда `y_current + rowspan` превышает количество `<tr>`, в результате `fill` создает лишние ряды, чего в браузере не наблюдается. С `colspan` наверняка та же ситуация. Пока просто ограничил `rowspan` сверху, но я явно чего-то не понимаю в стандарте.

Comment: Спасибо большое, с утра посмотрю и отвечу в полном объеме

Comment: Да, спасибо большое еще раз, Ваш алгоритм работает верно